# How to transfer data from one app to another app in same ios device?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to send some data from app to another app. How can I do it? I cannot use iCloud. I look on the side of Document provider, but I don't understand how use it.

http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2014/wwdc_2014_sample_code/newboxanintroductiontoiclouddocumentenhancementsinios8.0.zip

I download this example, but when I run it, it requires iCloud. I don't have Developer program.

Any idea, how can I solve it?
(sorry for my English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example of `UIDocumentInteractionController` to share files on iOS. iOS is designed to prevent apps from sharing data directly. So, `UIDocumentInteractionController` provided by Apple is the thing you should use to mimic something similar to direct sharing.

```
-(void)shareOnInstagram:(UIImage*)image {

    NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/image.igo"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:jpgPath error:nil];
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];

    NSURL *igImageHookFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:jpgPath];
    self.dic = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];
    self.dic.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
    [self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height) inView:self.view animated:YES];
}

- (UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL: (NSURL*) fileURL usingDelegate: (id <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>) interactionDelegate {
    UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL];
    interactionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;
    return interactionController;
}
```

See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/

Comment: @uninova hope this will help you, if I understood your situation correctly

Comment: If I want to transfer the data when both my apps are running, this won't work. Maybe I must use app extensions?

Comment: It will work fine. Look at what Instagram does with iPhone Hook. Extensions can be used for processing data from one app by some mechanisms provided by the extension's host app. This means that if you want your data from the first app to be processed by the second app extension and then returned to the first app, extensions would be the best approach. Check the docs by Apple for details.

Comment: self.dic.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
How did you get this and from where?
I need to do same thing with Whats App and Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

I finished it a few month ago. There is my solution using sockets here:

> ## Server part

#### DataProviderServer.h

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DataProviderServer : NSObject

- (void) startServer;

@end
```

#### DataProviderServer.m

```c
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#import  "DataProviderServer.h"

#define SERVER_PORT 8080

@implementation DataProviderServer

- (void) startServer
{
    CFSocketContext CTX = { 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL };
    CFSocketRef TCPServer = CFSocketCreate(
                                           kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                           PF_INET,
                                           SOCK_STREAM,
                                           IPPROTO_TCP,
                                           kCFSocketAcceptCallBack, (CFSocketCallBack)AcceptCallBack, &CTX);
    if (TCPServer == NULL)
    {
        NSLog(@"TCPServer = null");
        return ;
    }
    int optval = 1;
    setsockopt(CFSocketGetNative(TCPServer), SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
               (void *)&optval, sizeof(optval));

    struct sockaddr_in sin;

    memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_len = sizeof(sin);
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr= htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    NSData *address = [ NSData dataWithBytes: &sin length: sizeof(sin) ];
    if (CFSocketSetAddress(TCPServer, (CFDataRef) address) != kCFSocketSuccess)
    {
        NSLog(@"CFSocketSetAddress() failed");
        CFRelease(TCPServer);
        return ;
    }

    CFRunLoopSourceRef sourceRef =
    CFSocketCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, TCPServer, 0);
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), sourceRef, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    CFRelease(sourceRef);

    NSLog(@"Socket listening on port %d", SERVER_PORT);

    CFRunLoopRun();
}

void AcceptCallBack(
                    CFSocketRef socket,
                    CFSocketCallBackType type,
                    CFDataRef address,
                    const void *data,
                    void *info)
{
    CFReadStreamRef readStream = NULL;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream = NULL;
    CFIndex bytes;
    UInt8 buffer[128];
    UInt8 send_len = 0;

    CFSocketNativeHandle sock = *(CFSocketNativeHandle *) data;

    char * sendNumber = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 128);

    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket(kCFAllocatorDefault, sock,
                                 &readStream, &writeStream);

    if (!readStream || !writeStream)
    {
        close(sock);
        NSLog(@"CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket() failed");
        free(sendNumber);
        return;
    }

    CFReadStreamOpen(readStream);
    CFWriteStreamOpen(writeStream);

    unsigned count = 1;
    while (YES)
    {
        count++;
        sprintf(sendNumber, "%d", count);
        strcat(sendNumber, "\r\n");
        send_len = 0;
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        while (send_len < (strlen(sendNumber+1)))
        {
            if (CFWriteStreamCanAcceptBytes(writeStream))
            {
                bytes = CFWriteStreamWrite(writeStream,
                                           (unsigned char *) sendNumber + send_len,
                                           (strlen((sendNumber)+1) - send_len) );
                if (bytes < 0)
                {
                    NSLog(@"CFWriteStreamWrite() failed");
                    close(sock);
                    free(sendNumber);
                    return;
                }
                send_len += bytes;
            }
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
    return;
}
@end
```

#### How use

```c
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
                   ^{
                       self.server = [[DataProviderServer alloc] init];
                       [self.server startServer];
                   });
```

---

> ## Client part

#### DataRequesterClient.h

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DataRequesterClient : NSObject

- (void) sendMessage;
- (id) initWithDelegate: (id) delegate;

@end
```

#### DataRequesterClient.m

```c
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#import  "DataRequesterClientDelegate.h"
#import  "DataRequesterClient.h"

#define PORT 8080

static id <DataRequesterClientDelegate> delegateForSend; //TODO: global variable fixme

@interface DataRequesterClient ()

@end

@implementation DataRequesterClient

- (id) initWithDelegate: (id) delegate
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        delegateForSend = delegate;
    }
    return self;
}
- (void) sendMessage
{
    CFSocketContext CTX = { 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL };

    CFSocketRef TCPClient = CFSocketCreate(NULL, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP,
                               kCFSocketConnectCallBack, (CFSocketCallBack)ConnectCallBack, &CTX);
    if (TCPClient == NULL)
        return ;

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_len = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    CFDataRef connectAddr = CFDataCreate(NULL, (unsigned char *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

    CFSocketConnectToAddress(TCPClient, connectAddr, -1);
    CFRelease(connectAddr);
    CFRunLoopSourceRef sourceRef = CFSocketCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, TCPClient, 0);
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), sourceRef, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    CFRelease(sourceRef);

    CFRunLoopRun();
}

void ConnectCallBack(
                     CFSocketRef socket,
                     CFSocketCallBackType type,
                     CFDataRef address,
                     const void *data,
                     void * info )
{
    UInt8 buffer[128];
    CFSocketNativeHandle sock = CFSocketGetNative(socket);
    while (YES)
    {
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        NSLog(@"Recieved:%s", buffer);
        [delegateForSend didChangeString: [NSString stringWithUTF8String: (char *)buffer]];
    }
}
@end
```

#### How use

```c
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        self.client = [[DataRequesterClient alloc] initWithDelegate: self];
        [self.client sendMessage];
    });
```